# Using COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT when querying the UNION when the table headers are unknown?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I am currently using code of the form

```
SELECT * FROM ##Temp1
UNION
SELECT * FROM ##Temp2
```

which (because the temporary tables are populated from tables in 2 different databases, which each use a different collation) results in the error message

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.
```

Until now, when faced with an error such as this, I have been using the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT method, which has been possible because the headings contained within the tables have been constant.

However, I am now faced with a collation conflict between 2 tables where the table headings are not constant. How might I resolve this issue?

One possible solution that I can think of is to loop through the table headers for `##Temp1` in the `tempdb.dbo` table and generate a string dynamically which specifies the column headings used in the temporary tables. However, this seems unneccessarily clumsy.

Comment: Why don't you populate the temp tables "correctly", so they don't conflict in collation later? I know `SELECT .. INTO` is convenient, but you can always specify explicit columns and collations. Where this is truly not possible (all structures are dynamic) I'd question the wisdom of doing it all in T-SQL to begin with, but some sort of dynamic SQL seems unavoidable in this case.

Comment: "I'd question the wisdom of doing it all in T-SQL to begin with" - What's the alternative?

Comment: Client software -- PowerShell, C#, Integration Services, other ETL packages of your choice, take your pick. T-SQL gets extremely clumsy (and unreliable) if everything is dynamic, because the optimizer needs static structures.

Comment: I am fairly novice at all of this, but I am presuming that this is the sort of thing that you are refering to?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, Integration Services is the ETL package that comes with SQL Server. It's far from my favorite approach, but it's serviceable, and it has the benefit of being easy to schedule from jobs.

Comment: To add to Jeroen's first comment - why do you have databases that use different collations? And for no obvious reason? Fix that and your problem also goes away.